# How to find size of a vector when debugging in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I guess the title is self-explanatory. I'd like to monitor the size of a vector at various circumstances like when it is being passed to a function.. etc.
I could only find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249048/how-to-watch-the-size-of-a-c-stdvector-in-gdb) which is not using eclipse.
The vector can be a member of a class(if that helps)
thank you

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5713387/241631)?